# How to get features in openlayers with mapbox?

Tags: webgl, openlayers, mapbox-gl-js, mvt

I try to do it but it doesn't work, below is my main code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEqYI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y19lv.png)

Comment: Would be better to add code inline in the query and not as an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query the features on the Mapbox map

```
map.on('click', (e) => {
  const point = new mapboxgl.Point(e.pixel[0], e.pixel[1]);
  const features = mbMap.queryRenderedFeatures(point);
  console.log(features);
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mapbox-layer-forked-x8mocy?file=/main.js